# Pointer and Structure problems

Tags: c, pointers

I am suppose to be creating a memory map of this program for my class, but when I try to compile it, I get an error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('double *' and 'double *')
```

I am a student, please do not edit the code to print out memory locations, I need to write that myself.

```
main()
{
double testd;
int testi;
FILE *fpt;

struct frog {
    double *x, y;
}frog;

struct frog turtle, *apple, tv[3];

testi = 2;

apple = &turtle;
apple->x = &testd

*(turtle).x = 7.3;    //this is where im getting the error. 
(*apple).y = 3.6;

turtle.y = 1.5;

for (testi = 0; testi < 3; testi++)
    tv[testi].x = &(tv[(testi+1)%3].y);

*(tv[1].x) = 6.4;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `;` at the end of the previous line.

You are *not* wrong to dereference `*(turtle).x` instead of `*(turtle.x)`. The `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator, meaning those two statements are equivalent and you don't even need parentheses: you could just do `*turtle.x`.

Check out this site for [precedence ordering](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `;` at end of the previous line.

The compiler then interprets the `*` at the beginning of the line as a multiplication symbol and complains because that doesn't work out so well.

Comment: As a fun aside, the line that's getting parsed (`apple->x = &testd * turtle.x = 7.3;`) would silently compile if it weren't for the fact that `x` is a pointer to a double instead of a double. Imagine the debugging **hell** if `apple->x` was a double and the program compiled!

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot `;` after `apple->x = &testd` statement.

On a side note, in C you have to say `struct` before a structure, and `main` function is supposed to return an integer. You also need to include header files with declarations of data structures and functions that you are using (i.e. `stdio.h`). Not to mention that `//` comment style is C99, and C programmers don't really use it.. `/* */` comments are awesome.